# Surface Integrals, Origin Located Outside and Inside the Surface.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

Given that $S$ is a smooth and closed surface in the $xyz$-space, that $\vec{n}$ is the unit outward normal vector to $S$, and $r$ the distance between the origin and a point $(x,y,z)$.

Evaluate the integral below $1)$ when the origin is outside and $2)$ inside $S$.

$$\int_S \nabla \left( \frac{1}{r}\right) \cdot \vec{n}dS$$

The problem is, I do not understand how the position of the origin will affect the surface integral. The only solution that I came up with was using Gauss' Theorem (or the Divergence Theorem).

Given that, from Gauss' Theorem,

$$\int_S \nabla \left( \frac{1}{r}\right) \cdot \vec{n}dS = \iiint_V \nabla^2 \left( \frac{1}{r}\right)dV$$

and

$$\nabla^2 \left( \frac{1}{r}\right) = 0$$

Thus,

$$\int_S \nabla \left( \frac{1}{r}\right) \cdot \vec{n}dS = 0$$

But I can not tell if this is right, if it is, why? This solution is for the origin at the inside or outside? How should I calculate the other (if the solution is for the outside case, how to compute the inside case, and vice-versa?).

Comment: The divergence is zero at all points other than the origin and hence it matters whether origin is inside $S$ or outside. In case origin is outside, the integral is simply zero. Otherwise it is a constant $- 4 \pi$. Read dirac delta function.

Comment: @Math Lover, what do you think this has to do with the dirac delta function?

Comment: @MarkS. Just for this specific calculation which can be done using surface integral, not much but this specific vector field is one that we work with in electrodynamics when we talk about a point charge. How the charge density of a point charge blows up at the origin and is zero everywhere else is similar to the definition of Dirac Delta function. So suggested as additional reading.

Comment: @Iuri, your calculation $\nabla^2 \left( \frac{1}{r}\right) = 0$ isn't right for $r=0$. In fact, Gauss's theorem cannot be applied in a normal way if the origin is included since the divergence isn't continuous at $r=0$.

Comment: @MathLover, and MarkS., thank you guys for the quick replies, but I am still confused. If we have a surface $S$, the divergence in its interior is zero. Why just at the origin it is not?

Regarding the outside case, is it zero just because the vector field can only be evaluated until the border of $S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, we cannot apply the divergence theorem directly to the surface integral $\iint_{S}\nabla(1/r)\cdot n\mathrm{d}S$ when $S$ encloses the origin. The divergence theorem requires that the the vector field $\nabla(1/r)$ be "nice" on the region of space enclosed by $S$.

We can, however, apply the *generalized divergence theorem* which allows us adjust the our domain of integration to a more suitable surface.

For example, if $S$ encloses the origin, find $\epsilon>0$ so that the sphere $$S_{\epsilon}=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2=\epsilon^2\}$$ is contained in the region of space enclosed by $S$. Take $E$ as the region of space inside $S$ and outside $S_{\epsilon}$. Then $\nabla(1/r)$ is smooth on $E$ so we can appeal to the divergence theorem. $$\iiint_{E} \nabla^2 (1/r)\mathrm{d}V = \iint_{S}\nabla(1/r)\cdot n\mathrm{d}S-\iint_{S_{\epsilon}}\nabla(1/r)\cdot n \mathrm{d}S$$ Here $n$ is normal to the surface and points *away* from the origin. Because $\nabla^2(1/r)\equiv0$ on $E$, $$\iint_{S}\nabla(1/r)\cdot n\mathrm{d}S=\iint_{S_{\epsilon}}\nabla(1/r)\cdot n \mathrm{d}S$$ Since $\nabla(1/r)=-\frac{1}{\epsilon^3}(x,y,z)$ and $n=\frac{1}{\epsilon}(x,y,z)$ for any $(x,y,z)\in S_{\epsilon}$ we get $$\begin{eqnarray*} \iint_{S}\nabla(1/r)\cdot n\mathrm{d}S &=&\iint_{S_{\epsilon}}\nabla(1/r)\cdot n \mathrm{d}S \\&=& \iint_{S_{\epsilon}}\left(-\frac{1}{\epsilon^3}(x,y,z) \cdot\frac{1}{\epsilon}(x,y,z)\right)\mathrm{d}S \\ &=& -\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\iint_{S_{\epsilon}}\mathrm{d}S \\ &=& -\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\cdot 4\pi \epsilon^2 \\ &=& -4\pi\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: first, let me thank you for the quick reply. However, how can I be sure that $\nabla (1/r)$ is smooth and that $\nabla^2 (/r) = 0$? Maybe the last question is: why $\nabla (1/r)$ = -1/\epsilon^3$ and $n = 1/\epsilon$. I am sorry, for so many questions, I am still confused about this subject a lot!